# How can I show a thin blue bar for progress below title bar in webview just like chrome browser and uc browser

Tags: android-studio, android-webview

Am new in android studio programming. Pls does any one know How can I show a thin blue bar for progress below title bar in webview just like chrome browser and uc browser. I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i show spinner in titlebar when link is clicked on webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790886/how-can-i-show-spinner-in-titlebar-when-link-is-clicked-on-webview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick the code for Custom Progress Bar from [this link](http://codecops.blogspot.in/2017/09/chrome-like-progressbar-in-android.html)

and apply below code with webview

```
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(final WebView view, int progress) {

            pkProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProgressBar` component:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```