# How can i show spinner in titlebar when link is clicked on webview

Tags: android-studio, android-webview

Am new to android programming. I want to create a little spinner on my title bar in webview when a link is clicked. An example is the one in opera mini (on the top left) shown in [this photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BjWm.png) Pls I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Implement toolbar with progress bar or spinner. Then setup javascriptInterface for your webview and update toolbar's spinner when it's called from webview.